# Need Help - Uploading a file in RobotFramework is not working

Tags: robotframework

I'm facing a problem in uploading a file in the Robot framework.  I'm getting an "Element with locator <> Not found" error.

Wait until element is enabled works but file upload is not working

## Code Snippet

wait until element is enabled       xpath=/html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-build-audience/article/section/section/section/aside/div/div/section/app-file-uploader-document/div/div/div/div/label/span

Choose File         /html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-build-audience/article/section/section/section/aside/div/div/section/app-file-uploader-document/div/div/div/div/label/span    c:\TMP\Customer_List_june28.csv

## The result after Test Execution

Test Execution Result
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Element with locator '/html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-build-audience/article/section/section/section/aside/div/div/section/app-file-uploader-document/div/div/div/div/label/span' not found.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQE1c.png

Comment: `Choose File` keyword will look for <input> element and you are giving a locator to a "span".

Comment: Wonderful!!! It worked  :)  Are you a robot framework professional?

Comment: @rasjani -  what if the File Upload does not have an input element.  I've another place where I've to do file upload.  On checking saw that it does not have input  element

Not able to attach the screenshot......

Comment: I assume you are using SeleniumLibrary ? SeleniumTestability plug-in has workaround that allows upload files to a form like that.

Comment: Also Yes to be question.  I am contributor to SeleniumLibrary and Robot Framework.

Comment: @rasjani - can we please connect offfline.... its not working!